# Two same widget using jquery

Tags: html, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I'm new to JQuery, but I was wondering if anybody help me about the problem:

Consider you need to have 2 textbox with datepicker in a html page using jquery ui. as i know jquery is based on "ID" and not "Class". so i cannot use this:

```
<input type="text" name="dates2" class="datepicker">   --> DOESN'T WORK! 
<input type="text" name="dates3" class="datepicker">   --> DOESN'T WORK!
```

How ever if I want to use ID, just the first datepicker textbox works. as the same bellow:

```
<input type="text" name="dates2" id="datepicker">   -> WORKS!
<input type="text" name="dates2" id="datepicker">   -> DOESN'T WORK!
```

Its obviously each ID should be unique. however my question be so primitive but is there any possibility to have two datepicker (or slider or another widget) here? if the answer is Yes, so please help me how can i do it by JQueryUI?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand. But, you can have several of the same type on a page, separating them by the "id" attribute. For example, <input type="text" id="datePicker1" class="datepicker"> and <input type="text" id="datePicker2" class="datepicker">. In jQuery, you would select them like, $("#datePicker1") and $("#datePicker2").

Comment: *as i know jquery is based on "ID" and not "Class"* - what? Where did you come up with that? Did you even search how to select elements by class in jquery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Id is supposed to unique. Jquery id selector will get the first item based in the criteria, this is why the second element is unaffected.
I can sugget apply class on the elements.

```
<input type="text" name="dates2" class="datepicker">   
<input type="text" name="dates3" class="datepicker">
```

And then use class selector in jquery rather than id selector.

```
 <script>
   $(function() {
       $( ".datepicker" ).datepicker(); // class selector
   });
</script>
```

Comment: Your first segment of code was unaffected because you are probably using id selector there, sinces there was no id associated with elements, nothing happened.

Comment: Oh, seems right; infact i didnt care about this part of code: 
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker ()
as soon as i change it to class form as bellow, it works fine: 
$( ".datepicker" ).datepicker ()
-thank you rusty